# How to compare rows in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to compare 2 rows where the ID numbers are the same (for example rows 0 and 1) then delete the row with the smaller absolute income. Is there any way I can do this using just pandas functions and not looping through the rows using .itertuples(). I was thinking of using .shift and .apply, but I am not sure how to execute.

```
 Index   ID             Income  
 0       2011000070      55019   
 1       2011000070          0   
 2       2011000074      23879   
 3       2011000074          0   
 4       2011000078          0   
 5       2011000078          0   
 6       2011000118     -32500   
 7       2011000118          0
```

output I want:

```
 Index   ID             Income  
 0       2011000070      55019     
 2       2011000074      23879     
 4       2011000078          0     
 6       2011000118     -32500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) for indices of max absolute values and then select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['Income'].apply(lambda x: x.abs().idxmax()))
ID
2011000070    0
2011000074    2
2011000078    4
2011000118    6
Name: Income, dtype: int64

df = df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Income'].apply(lambda x: x.abs().idxmax())]
print (df)
   Index          ID  Income
0      0  2011000070   55019
2      2  2011000074   23879
4      4  2011000078       0
6      6  2011000118  -32500
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.loc[df['Income'].abs().groupby(df['ID']).idxmax()]
print (df)
   Index          ID  Income
0      0  2011000070   55019
2      2  2011000074   23879
4      4  2011000078       0
6      6  2011000118  -32500
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) plus sorting by `ID` and the absolute value of `Income` should solve your problem. Its `keep` parameter defaults to `"first"`, which is what you want.

```
df['Income_abs'] = df['Income'].apply(abs)

df.sort_values(['ID', 'Income_abs'], ascending=[True,False]).drop_duplicates(['ID']).drop('Income_abs',axis=1)
Out[26]: 
   Index          ID  Income
0      0  2011000070   55019
2      2  2011000074   23879
4      4  2011000078       0
6      6  2011000118  -32500
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work.

```
In [458]: df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.ix[x.Income.abs().idxmax()])
Out[458]:
   Index          ID  Income
0      0  2011000070   55019
1      2  2011000074   23879
2      4  2011000078       0
3      6  2011000118  -32500
```